# how to add fixed row header to a "display: grid" container

Tags: html, css

I want to add fixed row header to a "display: grid" container.
The container has scroll snap function.

The HTML looks as below.

```
  <div class="container">
    <div class="date date1">date1</div>
    <div class="date date2">date2</div>
    <div class="date date3">date3</div>
    <div class="card d1 p1">
      <div class="priority">priority</div>
      ..
      <div class="status">status</div>
    </div>
    <div class="card d1 p2">
      <div class="priority">priority</div>
      ..
      <div class="status">status</div>
    </div>
    ..
  </div>
```

I want date1 to date3 to be a header for the container, which shouldn't scroll and is shown always on the top of the container.

I want to make sure that scroll snap keeps working and that this code works on mobile.

I am creating this based on [this](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/07/css-scroll-snap). There are [demo](https://snap.glitch.me/product.html) and [source](https://glitch.com/edit/#!/quintessential-warp-chameleon?path=product.html:76:18), too. But it is hard for me to accomplish the same result.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/HHerbert/mx6d9L1p/282/)

Could you give me your help?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do they have to be in the same element?

Comment: no, they don't. It is ok for me that the final outcome has the same functionality.

Comment: Then separate those from the rest, create two grid layouts with their own container, add `position:fixed` to the top one and add `scroll-snap-type: y proximity;  scroll-padding-top:  calc(var(--bar-height) + var(--extra-space));` to the bottom one. Then put `scroll-snap-align: start;` on your `.card` class.

Comment: @ravb79 thank you for your advise. I tried fixing my code and finally reached to my desired result mostly. https://jsfiddle.net/HHerbert/mx6d9L1p/350/